# How can I define a mapped type that places an constraint on the value based on the key in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, mapped-types

I have the following types (simplified for brewity):

```
type Wrapper<T extends string> = {
    value: T
}

type Mapping = {
    [T in string]: Wrapper<T>
}
```

My goal with this is to constrain the possible values of `T` in `Wrapper` for any given key `T`. What I expected to happen if I did this:

```
const mapping: Mapping = {
    "a": { value: "b" },
}
```

is to have a compiler error because `"b"` is not assignable to `"a"` but for some reason this compiles. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `T in string` just results in `T` being `string`, so you get `type Mapping = {[k: string]: Wrapper<string>}`.  There is no specific type that works the way you want; you'd need a generic type like `Mapping<K>` and use it as a constraint in a helper identity function to give you the inference you want, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mL8Yvm).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a compile-time error you should create a mapped type with the constraint you want by using `as` keyword.

Try this:

```
type ConstrainedMapping<T extends string> = {
  [K in T]: Wrapper<K>;
};

const mapping = {
  "a": { value: "b" },
} as ConstrainedMapping<keyof typeof mapping>;
```

Is it also possible to create a utility function:

```
type ConstrainedMapping<T extends string> = {
  [K in T]: Wrapper<K>;
};

function map<T extends string>(mapping: ConstrainedMapping<T>): ConstrainedMapping<T> {
  return mapping;
}

// This won't compile!
const mapping = map({
  "a": { value: "b" },
});
```

Comment: IMHO, using `satisfies` instead of `as` gives better error messages and documents of the intent.

Comment: wow, this is the first time I hear about `satisfies`.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you can forget adding `as ConstrainedMapping`. I'd like something that forces a compiler error so I can't accidentally have the wrong key-value pairs.

Comment: @AdamArold Looks like you need to create a utility function. I will add it to my answer.