# How is this dynamic type lookup feature of Typescript called?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I've just looked into the source code (or rather the type headers) of discord.js and I found that it looks up the possible key-type combinations from an interface in this function:

```
public on<K extends keyof ClientEvents>(event: K, listener: (...args: ClientEvents[K]) => Awaitable<void>): this;
```

This is how the interface looks like:

```
export interface ClientEvents {
  applicationCommandPermissionsUpdate: [data: ApplicationCommandPermissionsUpdateData];
  autoModerationActionExecution: [autoModerationActionExecution: AutoModerationActionExecution];
  autoModerationRuleCreate: [autoModerationRule: AutoModerationRule];
  autoModerationRuleDelete: [autoModerationRule: AutoModerationRule];
  // ...
```

So basically it uses the `K` type to look up the type of the field with the appropriate name in `ClientEvents` (if I understand this correctly).

What's not clear is how to interpret the

```
autoModerationRuleCreate: [autoModerationRule: AutoModerationRule];
```

part. More specifically the tuple (???) `[autoModerationRule: AutoModerationRule]`.

How is this feature called? I looked at the Typescript reference but I didn't find this.

Comment: Which feature are you asking about? [Indexed accesses](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) are what I'd call "look up", but you're apparently not asking about that. Instead you're looking at a [labeled tuple](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) (yes, it's a tuple) and then...? What feature is the issue? Maybe [using tuples as rest params](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types)? I'd love to help but I'm not sure where to focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a labelled tuple

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements

This is particularly useful, for instance, when dealing with function parameters.

If you grab the parameters of a function (these are represented by a tuple type) and want to preserve names:

```
declare function a(b:number,c:string):unknown;

type P = Parameters<typeof a>;
```

Here `P` is of type `[b: number, c:string]` and we can make another function using this tuple, preserving parameter names:

```
declare function d(...args:P):number;
```

... now if we hover `d`, we'll see it has named parameters that match `a`. Previously, without labelled tuples (i.e. <TS v3.something), those parameter names would have been lost.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXygAoAjALlWQFtiQYAaMUgZwxi1QHMBKUtAa1Q4A7qgDcAWABQUjAE8ADggAKAXiWwolEBlpMAPHMU5EBAHwTJAekvxbAPQD8UqaEiwEKdNjzxghAHSBsBxMpEo8FNS0Fta2cfEJ8I5AA)

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. This is **exactly** what I was looking for a few weeks ago and now I found it by accident. If you want some extra karma you can put this answer to my prior question so that I can accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76076057/how-can-i-define-a-mapped-type-that-places-an-constraint-on-the-value-based-on-t   also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76076167/how-to-read-the-value-of-a-generic-type-parameter-in-typescript